# Debbuger to visualize image data

Tags: c++, c, debugging

Is there a debugger (free if possible) that can visualize image buffers during debugging sessions.
Something like:

1. I stop at breakpoint.
2. Then I select an image buffer, give directions of what the data is - RBG, CMYK, 8bit, float, whatever.
3. I am shown an image (or it is saved) made from the data.

Comment: I do not know of such debugger. In the recent years, however, I found myself using debuggers less and less, and instead relying on the debug output. This approach is more flexible, a lot faster and often allows you to get more information from each debugging session. You could dump intermediate state of your image buffer into image files named by the current timestamp, down to miliseconds, probably adding more character if name conflicts still occur.

Comment: Probably not. Not even Visual Studio will do that for Microsoft's own image types. You just have to save your images to disk in some appropriate format and visualise them using an external tool.

Comment: It should be possible with debuggers that can be extended, like [GDB with Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python).

Comment: @Septagram I recently had the "pleasure" to debug an application with printfs only. And it was quite a slow and painful experience. You always have to recompile the entire program an the more variables you have in it and the more frequently they change and etc. the more printfs you need. And to check even one variable it takes a recompile and a rerun. Debugging through logs is usable, but it doesn't scale well if you (for example) have to process each frame of a video and the problem is at the 145th frame or so.

Comment: @DimitarSlavchev, you have a valid point there about scaling... As for the `printf`, I imagine that would be quite painful, yes. In my case, however, I was using higher level classes for this (in a Qt framework, there's an excellent `QDebug` class, that allows you to send almost all Qt custom data types into it as into a stream). I imagine there's something similar in STL or Boost, but am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using gdb to debug your program, you can call your own(or some other library functions) that can visualize the image buffer for you(possibly in a separate window) from the gdb prompt once you reach a breakpoint.